# Low performance in React Native with Redux

Tags: performance, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have discovered some issues with performance in my react native app. It seems to be caused by react-redux bundle.

As you can see in the video

[Redux/Flux/setState comparing](https://youtu.be/D5L-RM5EY5E)

there is a significant delay between action dispatching and view rendering. On real devices it looks even worse.
There are no API calls in this example. Only simple actions dispatching and state changes. On other hand Facebook Flux implementation and simple call of setState work much more faster.

Any ideas how to improve the app performance?

I am using 
react: v15.2.1,
react-native: v0.29.2,
react-redux: v4.4.5,

**View**

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import {Map} from 'immutable';

import * as testActions from '../reducers/test/testActions';
import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux';

const actions = [
  testActions
];

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
      ...state
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  const creators = Map()
          .merge(...actions)
          .filter(value => typeof value === 'function')
          .toObject();

  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(creators, dispatch),
    dispatch
  };
}

........

<View style={styles.box}>
    {PRICE_FILTERS.map(filter =>{
        let price_cont_style = {};
        let price_text_style = {};
        if (filter.id == PRICE_FILTERS[3].id){
            price_cont_style.marginRight = 0;
        }
        if (filter.id == this.props.test.price){
            price_cont_style.backgroundColor = 'black';
            price_text_style.color = 'white';
        }
        return(
        <TouchableOpacity 
            key={filter.id} 
            style={[styles.price_cont, price_cont_style]} 
            onPress={()=>this.props.actions.setPrice(filter.id)}>
        <Text 
            style={[styles.price_text, price_text_style]}>
            {filter.label}
        </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    })}
</View>

......

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PerformanceTest);
```

**Actions**

```
const {
    TEST_SET_PRICE,
} = require('../../lib/constants').default;

export function setPrice(filter) {
  return {
    type: TEST_SET_PRICE,
    payload: filter
  };
}
```

**Reducer**

```
const {
    TEST_SET_PRICE,
} = require('../../lib/constants').default;
const InitialState = require('./testInitialState').default;
export default function authReducer(state = InitialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {

  case TEST_SET_PRICE:
        if (state.price!=action.payload){
            return {price:action.payload}
        } else{
            return state;
        }

    }
    return state;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As it turned out the cause of this issue is all components from navigation chain are staying unmounted and get rerendered behind of the current scene

See more details here
[Possible navigation issue in React Native/Redux app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38728435/possible-navigation-issue-in-react-native-redux-app)

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that in your video, you have redux-logger enabled, but flux and setState do not log into console.

It might be console.log that causes this performance drop. There is a [known issue](https://github.com/evgenyrodionov/redux-logger/issues/32#issuecomment-203866926), here is an [explanation](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5632#issuecomment-177299394).

Try to turn off console logging and see how it affects performance.

Comment: yes, i knew about this issue with redux-logger and tried to disable redux-logger and delete all console.log commands. It did not help. Same delays were present. In the video I left the logger and "RENDERING" message as a proof that the only action was dispatching and the only rendering performed when a button was pressed.